# Detect if a string has a quote in it and that quote has a comma inside it

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if strings that have a quote in them (denoted by quotation marks `""`) contain a comma right before the quote ends.

See these examples:

1)

```
He said "hi," then left.
```

2)

```
He said "hi", then left.
```

3)

```
He said "hi, ho", then left.
```

---

In `1)` there's a comma before the second quotation mark so this should be caught by the regex.

`2)` shouldn't be caught.

`3)` shouldn't be caught either.

---

**So I want to get a positive only if the string contains a quote and that quote has a comma inside it right before it ends.** I don't need anything except the true or false result from this regex.

I apologize that I don't have a regex to present - I've never worked with this and only need it for a single filter rule for reddit enhancement suite :S

Oh yeah this should be in javascript regex (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Should `"hi, ho,"` match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, any comma before a closing quotation mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead like so

```
"[^"]+,(?=")
```

Along with `.test()`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QVZevr/3/).

Comment: if you did't use the positive look ahead , would this make the regex any more less bullet proof ? Eg. (without positive lookahead ) , `/(\".+\,\")/g`

Comment: @Alexander: No, I guess not. `"[^"]*,"` would be fine as well, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Simple regexp will do the job:

```
/".*?,"/
```

Test it: https://regex101.com/r/3cl4h5/1

Comment: 'He said "hi"," then left.' wiill match with this regex.
Maybe this is better no?   `/.*("[^"]*,").*/`

Comment: @dfsq , not so much into regex's , but why did you use the `?` here ... just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik `?` prevents previous `*` from being "greedy", i.e. matching maximum possible occurrence, so non-greedy match will stop on the first `,"` sequence. Without `?` string like `"hi test ," ,"` from `He said "hi test ," ," then left` will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a1 = "He said \"hi,\" then left.";
String a2 = "He said \"hi\", then left.";
String test = ",\"";
```

if(a2.contains(test)) will give u false and if (a1.contains(test)) will give u true...

Answer (score 0):

don't know what to explain about this:

```js
let pattern = /"[^"]*,[^"]*"/g;

let strings = [
  'He said "hi," then left.',
  'He said "hi", then left.',
  'He said "hi, ho", then left.',
  '"He" said "hi," then "left."',
];

strings.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(str.match(pattern));
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```